# Are there super(calorie-)dense foods?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry, carbohydrates, proteins, fats

It’s commonly reported that there are 9 kilocalories per gram of fat, 7 per gram of alcohol, and 4 per gram of carbohydrates or protein. But these figures (with the exception of that for alcohol, which presumably means specifically ethyl alcohol since it is discussed in the context of a human diet) are approximations given to an assumed "dietary blend" of fats, carbohydrates, or proteins respectively.

My question is this: if you could obtain a pure sample of one specific molecular type of fat, carbohydrate, or protein, is there any molecule you could choose that would provide an energy density significantly greater than 9 kcal/gram?

(I’m asking because my friends and I over at Worldbuilding SE are trying to figure out whether you could make [Lembas bread without magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/56051/14255). My answer ("No") has been accepted and so now I’ve got raging impostor syndrome and I’m just wondering if it happens to be factually correct.)

Comment: Related: https://what-if.xkcd.com/126/

Comment: If you are a T-800 cyborg then your uranium fuel cell provides more than 9 calories of energy per gram.

Comment: Indeed, but as far as I'm aware no one classifies uranium as a carbohydrate, fat, or protein.  (Though, I wouldn't put it past the astrophysicists.)

Comment: Your answer looks OK. Pure fats have more or less the same energy value, and even gasoline is beating them only a little.

Comment: I'd say anything on the menu at McDonald's fits the bill.